# Have this problem an inconsistency?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem: Let $f$ be a function with the property that $f(0)=1, f^{\prime}(0)=1$, and $f(a+b)=f(a) f(b)$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. Show that $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and deduce that $f(x)=e^x$.

I noticed, however, that if I fix $0$ to $a$ or $b$ and make the remaining one be any real number (say $r$) on the $f(a+b)$ property and then derivate, I get $f^{\prime}(0+r)=f(0)^{\prime}f(r)+f^{\prime}(r)f(0)$ which results $f^{\prime}(r) = f(r) + f^{\prime}(r)$, hence $f(r)=0$ which means that for any real number $r$ the function returns $0$. Where would be the error in this reasoning, if there is it?

Comment: Why do you claim your statement about “if I fix 0” in the second paragraph? What is your justification?

Comment: What are the start values in the second part ? $f(a)=f(b)=0$ ? In this case , the solution actually is the $0$-function.

Comment: If, say, you fix $a=0$ and replace $b$ with $x$, you get $f(x)=f(0+x)=f(0)f(x)=f(x)$....where do you see a problem?

Comment: Where di d you get $f'(r) = f(r)+f'(r)$ from????

Comment: Please show how you get $f'(r) = f(r) + f'(r).$

Comment: I guess that you on $f(r+0)=f(r)f(0)$ incorrectly use the product rule to get $f'(r)=f'(r)f(0)+f(r)f'(0)=f'(r)+f(r),$ where it has been used that $f(0)=1=f'(0).$

Comment: @md2perpe why would that be incorrect?

Comment: Because $f(0)$ is a constant, so differentiating it yields $0$, *not* $f'(0)$

Comment: @Lorago oooohhhhhh... I see it now $f(0)^{\prime}$ is not the same as $f^{\prime}(0)$ , so to speak.